# Quantlib in Python

Tags: options, programming, quantlib

I have been playing around with QuantLib in Python and have been struggling with couple of simple tasks I would like to share and hopefully get help from the community

**debugging**:

The fact that it's c++ in the background makes any simple debugging exercises quite hard

*Example*:
I created a simple BlackScholesMertonProcess, I couldn't find a way to look into the interest rate, dividendyield or volatility used to create that process.

**conventions**:

another simple case, I created a ql.VanillaOption, priced greeks with a BlackScholesMertonProcess. I don't know the conventions used and can't find any docs explaining this. Delta seems to be dV/dS, vega [V(sig+1)-V(sig)]/1, gamma I couldn't figure out etc

Comment: You can screen the [source code at github](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib). The *conventions* used when calculating greeks are not seldomly quite different from shop to shop, so it really is up to the modeler, unfortunately.

Comment: Thx, I guess I have no other choice than getting back to c++. But I  don't think there is any documentation as well for c++, the only doc seems to be the code itself

Comment: Yep, that's my understanding as well. Good luck, though!